# VueJS method returns promise. How to display data in template

Tags: express, vue.js, axios, knex.js

VueJS front uses axios to retrieve data from Express API. Data returns as promise. I can't figure out how to display it in the template. The goal is to add this data to be displayed within a leaderboard, so I am doing a first query to get the username and the score(which is a sum) and then a second to get the data on the last single activity by each user.

Here is the code.

Leaderboard component:

```
<template>
  <table class="ui celled table">
    <thead>
      <tr><th colspan="4">Leaderboard for {{ currentGroup.name }}</th></tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Last Action</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Score</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(leader) in leaderboard" :key="leader.users_id">
        <td>
          <h4 class="ui image header">
            <img v-if="leader.avatar_url" :src="leader.avatar_url"  class="ui mini rounded image">
            <v-gravatar v-else :email="leader.email" class="ui mini rounded image" />
            <div class="content">
              {{leader.username}}
            </div>
          </h4>
        </td>
        <td>{{ lastActByUser(leader.users_id).deed }}</td>
        <td></td>
        <!-- <td>{{ lastAct(leader.id).deed }}</td>
        <td>{{ moment(lastAct(leader.id).created_at).strftime("%A, %d %b %Y %l:%M %p") }}</td> -->
        <td>{{leader.count}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>

<script>
import moment from 'moment-strftime'
import _ from 'lodash'
import ReportsService from '@/services/ReportsService'
import ActsService from '@/services/ActsService'
export default {
  name: "Leaderboard",
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },
  computed: {
    leaderboard () {
      return this.$store.getters.leaderboard;
    },
    currentGroup () {
      return this.$store.getters.currentGroup;
    }
    // ,
    // lastAct (userId) {
    //   return _.orderBy(this.actsByUser(userId), 'created_at')[0];
    // }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.getLeaderboard();
  },
  methods: {
    getLeaderboard: async function () {
      console.log('currentGroup: ', this.$store.getters.currentGroup)
      this.$store.dispatch("updateLeaderboard", this.$store.getters.currentGroup);
    },
    moment: function (datetime) {
      return moment(datetime);
    }
    ,
    async lastActByUser (leader_id) {
      console.log('getting last act for user')
      const response = await ActsService.fetchLastActByUser ({
        userId: leader_id
      });
      this.deed = response.data.deed
      this.created_at = response.data.created_at
      console.log('lastAct response: ', response.data)
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

here is ActsService:

```
import Api from '@/services/Api'

export default {
  fetchActs () {
    return Api().get('acts')
  },

...

  fetchLastActByUser (params) {
    console.log('calling the last act service with userId: ', params.userId)
    return Api().post('acts/last_by_user', params)
  },

}
```

here is the Express route:

```
const express = require('express');
const User = require('../models/User');
const auth = require('../middlewares/authenticate');
const Act = require('../models/Act');

let router = express.Router();

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const acts = await Act
    .query().eager('user');
  res.json(acts);
});

...
// GET last act for specified user
router.post('/last_by_user', async (req, res, next) => {
  const lastAct = await Act
    .query()
    .findOne({
      users_id: req.body.userId
    });
  console.log('lastAct on server side is: ', lastAct)
  res.json(lastAct);
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: So if I understand you correctly you want to display the leaderboard data that you fetch from an external API in your template? If I see correctly you are already storing that in your vuex store and pulling that out of your store using a computed getter. Correct?

Comment: yes. the leaderboard correctly pulls and displays usernames ranked by the total number of acts by each user.  Now i want to include info re: the last act for each user, eg. the last thing they did and when they did it.

Comment: Can you give some more data? How does your vuex store look like? What does the JSON data you pull from the server look like? Try and do the same thing you did for the leaderboard.

Comment: @techouse I am getting the data from the backen s.t that console.log('lastAct response: ', response.data), returns data like lastAct response:  {id: 1, deed: "Writing", users_id: 1, created_at: "2019-09-23T15:28:22.723Z", updated_at: "2019-09-23T15:28:22.723Z"}.  but i can't get the data to show in the template.  e.g. {{ lastActByUser(leader.users_id) }} returns [object Promise]

Comment: Of course it returns that. You're mixing apples and oranges. You can not call an asynchronous method synchronously in the template. You will have to resolve the Promise in a `.then()` method and update your `data` property there. Only then can you print that `data` property in the template. Read this maybe https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises

Comment: I thought using aync/await meant I didn't need to use .then()

Comment: There's no or/either. Use both.  `async/await` is basically syntactic sugar. An `async` method simply returns a `Promise`. https://hackernoon.com/should-i-use-promises-or-async-await-126ab5c98789

Comment: Now  I have tried this.UserLastAct =response.data and then initializing the data object  lastUserAct and calling {{ lastUserAct.deed }} in the template which doesn't thro error but returns nothing

Comment: What do the Vue dev tools say is in your data object?